# Selecting all multipart features in feature class using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, multipart

How do I select and visualize all multipart features in a feature class using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: ArcPy Polygon class considers a polygon with a hole in it as "multipart", so multipart doesn't equate to multipolygon.  It would be good to clarify if you are interested in WKT `POLYGON` or `MULTIPOLYGON`.

Answer (score 1):

This script run in a Python notebook will work to select multipart features.

```
import arcpy


arcpy.env.workspace = r"path_to_your_geodatabase_or_folder"
input_feature_class = "name_of_your_feature_class"


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_feature_class, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Check if the geometry is multipart
        if row[1].isMultipart:
            # Select the feature
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(input_feature_class, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", "OBJECTID = " + str(row[0]))

print("Selection complete")
```

Comment: You may find your script run significantly faster if you store the OID in a list on each test of if multipart then build a where clause from that and run the select layer by attribute tool once.

Comment: The number of features in an IN selection list should probably be limited, though, and if most of the features are multipart, selecting for singlepart, then flipping the selection could be faster.

Comment: setSelectionSet is way faster than any query